# Any better term than "Postscript"?

Tags: synonyms, formality, colloquialisms, postscript

There was a [Postscript section in my English Course-book](http://www.englishservice.cz/download/Postscript%20sections%20Upper%20Int.pdf), which simply teaches the colloquial English phrases as in "Give me a lift", "Let me have a look", "There is no point", etc. But "postscript" won't return any relevant results in Google, so I thought there might be a better expressive/suitable term for this phrases. Is there really?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. Do you want (a) a word to describe a section added onto the end of something, or (b) a word to describe the phrases you listed? In either event, *postscript* wouldn't seem the best option.

Comment: (b). search "postscript" in these pages @Kelly http://www.mfa-spb.ru/page_3784.html http://www.kursy-volgograd.ru/id_4126.php and see the example usages/sentences.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like RegDwight may have answered your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrases are actually titled "social expressions", and that's what I would google for. I might throw in the word "common" for good measure, and [search for "common social expressions"](http://www.google.com/search?q=common+social+expressions).

The word *postscript* has nothing to do with the phrases at hand. It simply means "addendum to the book".

Comment: you take the hardest of questions :D

Comment: For 10 years I thought the "postscript" section was the name of the informal expressions commonly used, and they would have granted me the key for fluent speaking. Disappointment ;(

Answer (score 1):

"Post script" is a phrase derived from Latin "post scriptum", meaning "after the writing", and is almost exclusively used to signal an addition to a letter after the closing salutation.  It is also usually abbreviated "P.S."

The construction "PostScript" is a trademark for a software package used in publishing and formatting of documents.  I think the appearance of this in the heading of your study book appendix is a result of the author/editor using the default construction of the page header and not proofreading carefully enough to notice that the trademark was not relevant to the subject matter.

Comment: I can buy *postscript* not getting relevant hits on google because of confusion with the software with the same name. The section header having that name in the publishing software defaults is a stretch.